# Scaling div to its parent while keeping absolute positions inside

Tags: html, css

I need to display an image (floor plan), place multiple icons (cameras) on top of it, and scale that image (its div container) to its parent.

If it would be just about the image, simple `max-width: 100%` works ok. But I need to maintain correct camera positions on top of it.

Following example shows my current status. Now I need to somehow scale the `.container` to fit the top level div (here I set 400px width, but in real life that will be dynamic/responsive), while keeping the camera icons on correct positions.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.camera {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 400px">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400">
    <div class="camera" style="left: 50px; top: 50px"></div>
    <div class="camera" style="left: 300px; top: 50px"></div>
    <div class="camera" style="left: 550px; top: 350px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible somehow via CSS? I know I could produce the floor plan with camera icons as SVG and scale just the image via `max-width`, but if possible, I would rather not construct the SVG.

Few notes:

- I know the exact size of the image
- The image size will be different for each one of them
- I do not know the parent div size (it can change)

I am looking for a CSS way, I know how to do this manually via JS, computing the scale factor manually and using `transform: scale(...)`.

Comment: Does  scaling via transform: e.g. `transform:scale(0.1)` on the .container help?

Comment: I would have to do that via JS, getting the top level div width first and calculating the rest. I was looking for a way via CSS only (and I would probably rather go the SVG way instead of using JS).

Comment: Don't use hardcoded pixel values in your positioning...use percentages. For instance - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: Right, that could be the way to go, I could compute the percentage on server side and serve that instead of absolute positions! TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by positioning your cameras using %-ages rather than px (you could also make their sizes proportional too). Then you can change the size of the container and they'll stay positioned relative to it.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
#outer{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
.camera {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: darkred;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px" id="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400">
    <div class="camera" style="left: 5%; top: 5%"></div>
    <div class="camera" style="left: 30%; top: 20%"></div>
    <div class="camera" style="left: 50%; top: 50%"></div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div style="width: 200px" id="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400">
    <div class="camera" style="left: 5%; top: 5%"></div>
    <div class="camera" style="left: 30%; top: 20%"></div>
    <div class="camera" style="left: 50%; top: 50%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```